# SQL datetime Jan 25, 2019 4:06:45 PM

Tags: sql, datetime-format

I'd like get my date time from SQL in the format `Jan 25, 2019 4:06:45 PM`, but I could not find a way to obtain it.

Many thanks for your help.

Andrea

Comment: What database platform, and what client code?  Please provide more details, and example code/queries?

Comment: Just the select format. something like 
select GETDATE()
SELECT replace(convert(NVARCHAR, getdate(), 106), ' ', '/')

Comment: When you use the tag SQL, it's also important to add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using as well, as the syntax and functionality varies between them. There's a big suggestion displayed on the page when you're writing your question and add that SQL tag that suggests you do so - please do not ignore it in the future. It's a waste of both your time and ours if you're not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server (that, based on the syntax in your comment, you are *maybe* using), you can use [the `FORMAT` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to format a date. It takes an optional argument, called the *culture*, that represents the locale of the output language (if not provided, the current session language is used) :

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt', 'en-US')
```

Yields : `Jan 25, 2019 9:20 PM`

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=c4a0ed1eac40dc18d07db1ed2fc9fea5)**

Comment: Also, if you don't want the leading zero on the hours you can always take one of the lower case h out and it will print the same as you have in the title.

Comment: @dmoore1181 : yes, good catch, thanks ! I updated the answer (and the fiddle).

Answer (score -1):

With MySQL/MariaDB

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(ts_col, "%b %d, %Y %l:%i:%s %p") from my_tab;
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(ts_col, "%b %d, %Y %r") from my_tab;
```

Gets

```
Jan 25, 2019 9:19:41 PM
```

or

```
Jan 25, 2019 09:19:41 PM
```

respectively.

BTW, when you're asking SQL questions you really need to tell us what SQL engine you're running on.